# How to get Account management and Cart section only in Products page

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management

I want to show account management and cart section only in products page I removed it showing in other pages using header.phtml now I want it in products page ONLY please help me in doing this.

[image: in this way]

Comment: someone please help

Comment: can you please post your page.xml/local.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/mini.phtml" before="-">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type>
    <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                        <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

Paste this code in middle of reference blocks of whatever pages you want to enable this thing and put this code in header section.
for example as you said you need this in products page then put this code in between `<catalog_product_view>....</catalog_product_view>` this section in the same way for all the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="main-slider" as="main-slider" translate="label">
                <label>Page Slider</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="main-banner" as="main-banner" translate="label">
                <label>Page Banner</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="footer-banner" as="footer-banner" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer Banner</label>
            </block>

        </reference>

        <reference name="head">

        <!-- add javascript -->

            <!-- jquery : LOADING DYNAMICALLY -->
            <!--<action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js</script></action>-->

            <!-- bootstrap plugins -->
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/bootstrap/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>eternal/html5shiv.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>

            <!-- jquery plugins -->
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.easing.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.imgpreload.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.bgpos.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.flexslider.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.colorbox-min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/prettyCheckable.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/jquery/scrolltopcontrol.js</script></action>

            <!-- custom script -->
            <action method="addJs"><script>eternal/venedor.js</script></action>

        <!-- add stylesheet -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/select.css</name><params/></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/jquery/flexslider.css</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/jquery/colorbox.css</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/jquery/jscrollpane.css</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/jquery/prettyCheckable.css</name><params/></action>

            <!-- base style -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-venedor.css</name><params/></action>
            <!-- system config design -->
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet helper="venedor/config/getCssFile" /></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet helper="venedor/config/getCssResponsiveFile" /></action>

            <!-- custom style -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/skin.css</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet helper="venedor/config/getCssSkinResponsiveFile" /></action>

            <!-- CSS for IE -->
            <action method="addCssIe"><css>css/styles-ie.css</css></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie7.css</name><params/><if>lte IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie8.css</name><params/><if>lte IE 8</if></action>

            <!-- Respond JS -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>eternal/respond.min.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" name="body_after_scripts" template="page/html/body_after_scripts.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <!-- header -->
        <reference name="header">
            <!-- add currency switcher -->
            <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>

            <!-- add mini cart to the header : new template -->
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/mini.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>

        </reference>

        <!-- top links -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <!-- change top links template -->
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/template/top_links.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <!-- remove checkout links -->
            <!--<remove name="checkout_cart_link" />-->
        </reference>

        <!-- footer -->
        <reference name="footer">
            <!-- Social blocks -->
            <block type="venedor/social_twittertweets" name="social_twitter_tweets" template="eternal/venedor/twitter_tweets.phtml"/>
            <block type="venedor/social_twittertweets" name="social_twitter_tweets_footer" template="eternal/venedor/twitter_tweets_footer.phtml"/>
            <block type="venedor/social_facebookfans" name="social_facebook_fans" template="eternal/venedor/facebook_fans.phtml"/>

            <!-- custom social links -->
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_footer_social_links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_footer_social_links</block_id></action>
            </block>

            <!-- newsletter -->
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <!-- remove unnecessary blocks -->
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="product.clone_prices"/>

        <!-- remove sidebar blocks -->

        <!-- uncomment these tags to remove selected blocks -->
        <!--
        <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
        <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
        <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>
        <remove name="reorder"/>
        -->
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
        <remove name="right.poll"/>

        <!-- left -->
        <reference name="left">
            <action ifconfig="venedor_setting/footer/show_subscribe" method="unsetChild"><name>left.newsletter</name></action>
        </reference>

        <!-- right -->
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>

<!-- newsletter -->
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="right.newsletter" before="-" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>

            <action ifconfig="venedor_setting/footer/show_subscribe" method="unsetChild"><name>right.newsletter</name></action>

            <!-- new products -->
            <block type="venedor/product_list_featured" name="featured.products" template="catalog/product/list/featured_sidebar.phtml">
                <action method="setIsNew"><src>1</src></action>
                <action method="setIsRandom"><src>1</src></action>
                <action method="setProductCount"><src>16</src></action>
                <action method="setBlockName"><src>New Products</src></action>
            </block>   

            <!-- add advertising block in right sidebar -->
            <block type="core/template" name="right.venedor.ads" template="eternal/venedor/advertising.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </default>

<!-- CUSTOMER-->

    <!-- Customer logged in -->
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

    <!-- Customer logged out -->
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
        </reference>        
    </customer_logged_out>  

    <!-- Customer account -->
    <customer_account> 
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <!-- remove cart sidebar -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
        </reference> 
    </customer_account>


<!-- CATALOG -->

    <!-- Default category (without layered navigation) -->
    <catalog_category_default>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.banner" template="catalog/category/banner.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- remove left navigation -->
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
            <!-- remove currency switcher -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
        </reference>        

        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.rightnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </catalog_category_default>

    <!-- Category with layered navigation -->
    <catalog_category_layered>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.banner" template="catalog/category/banner.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- remove left navigation -->
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
            <!-- remove currency switcher -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
        </reference> 

        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.rightnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </catalog_category_layered>

    <!-- Catalog product view -->
    <catalog_product_view>
        <!-- change default template -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <!-- insert related products into product view and remove them from the right sidebar -->
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="insert">
                <block>catalog.product.related</block>
            </action>

            <!-- change review summary template: removed links to review page. used new template file. -->
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary_nolinks.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product_brand" template="catalog/product/view/brand.phtml"/>

            <!-- add tabs -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                <!-- short description -->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>short_description</alias><title>Overview</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/short_description.phtml</template></action>

                <!-- description -->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Info</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>

                <!-- add reviews -->
                <!-- see the second part: reference name="tabreviews".  Do not change 'tabreviews' alias. It is needed in JS script in catalog/product/view.phtml -->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>tabreviews</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>

                <!-- cross sell products -->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>crosssell</alias><title>Cross Sells</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>catalog/product/view/crosssell.phtml</template></action>

                <!-- add tags -->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag"><alias>product.tags</alias><title>Product Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>tag/list.phtml</template></action>                

            </block>

            <!-- up sell products: set columns count and max number of displayed items -->
            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>24</limit></action>
            </block>

        </reference>

        <!-- reviews tab -->
        <reference name="tabreviews">
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                    <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <!-- remove product tags block (already inserted as a tab) -->
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
        </reference>

        <!-- remove "add to wishlist/compare" links from options box. It is already inserted on product view. -->
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.addto</name></action>
        </reference>

    </catalog_product_view>

    <catalog_product_compare_index translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Compare Products</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Compare Products</label><title>Compare Products</title></crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>        
    </catalog_product_compare_index>

<!-- Reviews -->
    <review_product_list>
        <!-- same as catalog_product_view -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>        
    </review_product_list>

<!-- SEARCH -->

    <!-- Quick search -->
    <catalogsearch_result_index>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- remove currency switcher -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
        <!-- remove layer navigation -->
            <remove name="catalogsearch.leftnav" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.rightnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    <!-- Advanced search -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_index>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- remove currency switcher -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>right_currency</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_index>

    <!-- Advanced search results -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="right">
            <!-- remove currency switcher -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>right_currency</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

<!-- CHECKOUT -->
    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Shopping Cart</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Checkout</label><title>Checkout</title></crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Shopping Cart</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Shopping Cart</label><title>Shopping Cart</title></crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

<!-- CONTACT -->
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Contact Us</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo><label>Contact Us</label><title>Contact Us</title></crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="contactForm">
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_contact_details">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_contact_details</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>

</layout>
```